# How long does HttpClient wait for a response (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Suppose I create a rest endpoint that sleeps for 10 minutes before sending a response and I use HttpClient in angular. Will the HttpClient wait for 10 minutes for the response? In general, does it keep waiting forever unless I use something like waitUntil?

I searched for this in docs but couldn't find much info. If you can provide a source documenting the behaviour that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not up to Angular, it's your browser that actually makes the request. There may be other systems (proxies) in-between with their own timeouts, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Consider making this an answer so that I can accept it and close this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using increasing `HTTP` request time  using Interceptor like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).timeout(600000, Observable.throw("Request timed out"));
    // 10 minute(600000 milliseconds ) would be the global default for example
  }
}
```

Comment: That sets the timeout for the *observable*, not the actual request.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you please provide some more info on that? I use a TimeoutInterceptor in my providers: [
        [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TimeoutInterceptor, multi: true }],
        [{ provide: DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, useValue: 600000 }], //in ms] and if the time exceeds the limit set, the Status in the Network tab is (canceled). Doesn't it cancel the actual call? Thank you in advance.